# node.js minimal setup and for what is the package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i start off with writing my own node.js app and the only thing i want is to include a package for saml.

So i was wondering what is the minimal requirement for my app.

I was just creating a node.js file and then i installed the package by:
`node install some-saml-passports-package`.

I got this warning after installation:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../mynodeapp/package.json'
```

I removed the package and created a `package.json` file. Which results in a parsing error because there was no content inside.

I have read that I only need a `package.json` when I plan to create my own package. Also I read something about local and global installation of package files in npm. Well, i need a bit of clarification for my doing.

What is the use of `package.json`?
Do I need it when I only want to create a standalone app in node with one dependency to an existing package?
Is it recommended even if I don't need it at all?

Comment: `npm init` is the correct way to create package.json file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no minimum requirement for node.js application. The `package.json` is only required to manage your application for dependencies, module descriptions , handle npm scripts etc. You can install packages without `package.json`, just don't use the `--save` flag with `npm install`. E.g.:

`npm install <package_name>` - you can still run your node application without any problem. But I will suggest you to add a `package.json` file and add following:

```
{
    "name": "<package_name>",
    "version": "<version>", //0.0.1 for starters
    "description": "",
    "main": "<entry point of application>", // example: app.js , index.js etc
    ,
    "author": "<your name>",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

You can create this by adding it manually or just execute `npm init` in your project root directory and answer some basic questions in console.

Here are some useful links:

[npm init](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)

[how to use package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json)

Comment: so when i enter a package in the dependecy  tag, do i still need to do `node install package`or is this done implicitly on startup?

Comment: yes you have to do `npm install` after every change you make to package dependencies in package.json, you don't have to mention package name npm will automatically read package.json and install all packages, just run `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

The minimal file is:

```
{
}
```

Now you can start using commands like `npm install web3 --save` and they will save onto this file.

Answer (score 2):

Create package.json via `npm init` command.
Package.json contains data about your project and what is more important for standalone app - it contains dependencies list. You can install all dependencies from package.json with `npm install`.

If you want to install package and save it in package.json type `npm install package-name --save`.